# Structuring return result enums

Tags: java, enums, conventions

I am looking for a way where I can structure java enums in an efficient / elegant way. These enums hold return results.

- there are functions like "delete item" (enums: OK, DOESNT_EXIST, ACCESS_DENIED..) or create item (OK, ALREADY_EXISTS, ACCESS_DENIED..), changeItem (OK, INVALID_PARAMETER, INVALID_CLASS, ACCESS_DENIED)
- As you see they have both own and shared enums. therefore some enums should be implemented in every return function (OK, ACCESS_DENIED), while others are exclusive (DOESNT_EXIST, ALREADY_EXISTS...).
- also, there are complex functions like changeOrCreate where an item may be created if it does not exist and changed elsewise (enums: all createItem enums, all changeItem enums).

Basically I can

1. build different enums for every function (createItemResult, changeItemResult..) or
2. put them all into one RESULT enum class.

But whatever I choose I can never accomplish all of these

- When a complex function like "changeOrCreate" fails, I want to know whether the returned enum "ACCESS_DENIED" was caused by the creation or the change.
- I would highly prefer the caller of any function getting the same enumType
- (I would prefer the functions no to be able to return illegal enums. e.g.: createUser shouldnt have DOESNT_EXIST)

Any ideas? Or is there any convention for return type enums?

Update:
The reason I cannot use (Non-Standard-)Exceptions is that I have to provide an API and it was a requirement that no Exceptions can be thrown.

Comment: If you realy want to have separate enum for every possible outcome of some set of functions, than having those as separate enums is as good as having 1 large enum. (both are kind of not-commonly-used aproaches to me anyway)

Comment: what is the common way?

Comment: Common way: Throwing an exception when an error occurs.

Comment: With error code you' ll handle lot of if-else following the result... with exception you just catch (if you do something with it) the exception. Your code will be less verbose.

Answer (score 1):

> When a complex function like "changeOrCreate" fails, I want to know whether the returned enum "ACCESS_DENIED" was caused by the creation or the change.

Then name them `CREATE_DENIED` and `CHANGE_DENIED`, or something like that.

> I would highly prefer the caller of any function getting the same enumType

So do the one RESULT enum class you suggested.

> I would prefer the functions no to be able to return illegal enums.

Since you're writing the functions, you control which of the enums it returns, i.e. you make sure `createUser` never returns `DOESNT_EXIST`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're using HTTP status codes in Java, and while this can work well for your program, is not an elegant way to write Java programs.

Java has exceptions for two reasons (that I know of):

- Something unexpected happened, and the program doesn't know how to handle it. What you do: Throw it to the next layer~!
- Something expected happened, so you catch it, and resolve it.

Since you are expecting an exception, what this means for you is:

Create some classes for your enum-cases, like UserNotAuthorizedException, (or just use the built-in AuthenticationException), and throw those to your program.

If you want to know who didn't get access you can either select it with an argument to your exception (an ID for each use-case, the instance that failed (which can include a static type), or even a string. It's up to you), you can create a subclass...

At the end of the day, Java likes classes.

Comment: You are somewhat right, I catch server messages (not http though). Unfortunately I am not allowed to use (Non-Standard-)Exceptions. I have to provide an API and it was a requirement by others that there are no exceptions.

Comment: You can internally use Exceptions to create control flow. Your internal program must catch all exceptions if your "superiors" demand no exceptions. As long as your function doesn't "throws Exception", you should be fine. You can use AuthenticationException, since it is a standard one (needs to be imported, though).